# Iterate over constantly modified List

Tags: c#, wpf, list, user-interface

So i'm reading a constant serial data stream from my arduino to validate some things in my program. However displaying these lock up the UI thread. So my "solution" is to make a buffer that keeps the serial data and then use a timer to put the data on the UI thread with intervals instead of a constant stream.

My code:

```
public partial class ConsoleWindow : Window
{
    private SerialPort _serialPort;
    private List<string> bufferStrings = new List<string>();
    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public ConsoleWindow(ref SerialPort serialPort)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (serialPort != null)
        {
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,80);
            timer.Tick += PopQueue;
            _serialPort = serialPort;
            _serialPort.DataReceived += DataReceived;
            timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void PopQueue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var queue = bufferStrings;
        foreach (var queueString in queue)
        {
            AppendText(queueString);
        }
        bufferStrings.Clear();
    }

    private void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_serialPort != null)
        {
            bufferStrings.Add(((SerialPort)sender).ReadLine());
            //AppendText(((SerialPort) sender).ReadLine());
        }
    }

    public void AppendText(string text)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (Output.Inlines.Count > 100)
            {
                Output.Inlines.Remove(Output.Inlines.FirstInline);
            }

            Output.Inlines.Add(text);
            ScrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
        });
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that I get an exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'`. I know why it happens, but i have no idea how i could do this properly. And no idea of what to google either.

Comment: @elgonzo I fear using a concurrent collection could theoretically result in the same issue the PO is trying to fix if the data are enqueued faster than they are dequeued.

Comment: @Pragmateek, yeah, you are right. If the Arduino pushes data fast enough for a long enough time, the program could possibly get stuck in the PopQueue method. Oopsie! There are probably ways around this (like only popping up to a maximum number of elements per call of _PopQueue_), but `lock` is in comparison simpler to implement...

Comment: Yes exactly. Another way may be poping during a maximum period like 100ms.

Comment: If you're putting so many items in that taking them out is going to take too long then a `lock` will solve one problem while creating another. Requests to add more items will block while you're taking items out. And if you're actually putting in that many items then that's a real big problem. This is exactly the reason why you would use a `ConcurrentQueue`. You need to be able to put items in and take them out at the same time, not force one to stop and wait for the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two solutions you can take to prevent the `InvalidOperationException`:

1. Copy the buffer to a new list before iterating through its contents. You can do so by calling `var queue = bufferStrings.ToList();` Note that you must include `using System.Linq;` to use `ToList()`.
2. Make the iteration thread safe by surrounding it with the `lock` keyword:

   ```
   private void PopQueue(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       lock(bufferStrings)
       {
           foreach (var queueString in bufferStrings)
           {
               AppendText(queueString);
           }
           bufferStrings.Clear();
       }
   }

   private void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (_serialPort != null)
       {
           lock(bufferStrings)
           {
               bufferStrings.Add(((SerialPort)sender).ReadLine());
               //AppendText(((SerialPort) sender).ReadLine());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You must also `lock` on the producing part in `DataReceived`, otherwise the `lock` is useless.

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I'll still take a look at System.Collections.Concurrent. As this seems to be quite resource intensive (might just be the constant GUI updates though).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to synchronize the accesses to the `bufferStrings` queue using a `Monitor` through the `lock` construct:

```
private void PopQueue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (bufferStrings)
    {
        foreach (var queueString in bufferStrings)
        {
            AppendText(queueString);
        }
        bufferStrings.Clear();
    }
}

private void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_serialPort != null)
    {
        lock (bufferStrings)
        {
            bufferStrings.Add(((SerialPort)sender).ReadLine());
            //AppendText(((SerialPort) sender).ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while you're iterating over an `IEnumerable` using `foreach`, the collection is being changed in another thread.

What you need is a collection that you can concurrently add to and read from.

At the top of the file add

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
```

Change this:

```
private List<string> bufferStrings = new List<string>();
```

to

```
private ConcurrentQueue<string> bufferStrings = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
```

Change

```
bufferStrings.Add(((SerialPort)sender).ReadLine());
```

to

```
bufferStrings.Enqueue(((SerialPort)sender).ReadLine());
```

Then, you can read from the queue without worrying about whether something else is writing to it:

```
private void PopQueue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (bufferStrings.TryDequeue(out string dequeued))
        AppendText(dequeued);
}
```

This just keeps trying to take items out the queue until there are no more. `TryDequeue` returns false when the queue is empty. If you keep adding items while this method is running it will just keep processing them.

[ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Reactive Extensions provide most of this functionality out of the box.

Check out [Intro to RX](http://introtorx.com/), [Observable Timer](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableTimer), [Replacing Events](https://rehansaeed.com/reactive-extensions-part1-replacing-events/), [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/)